# Scaling Canvas's that consist of Paths imported into Blend from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I have imported a text that was created in Adobe Illustrator into Expression Blend 4 and arrived with the following set of Paths:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="TextBlock" Height="84" Margin="1,0,80,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Path Data="F1M234.41795,334.1802L224.54295,334.1802L224.54295,329.77395L224.41795,329.77395C222.16795,333.2427,218.85545,334.96145,214.5117,334.96145C210.5117,334.96145,207.29295,333.5552,204.85545,330.727075C202.41795,327.914575,201.1992,323.96145,201.1992,318.89895C201.1992,313.6177,202.54295,309.3677,205.23045,306.1802C207.91795,302.9927,211.433575,301.39895,215.79295,301.39895C219.91795,301.39895,222.79295,302.883325,224.41795,305.83645L224.54295,305.83645L224.54295,286.8052L234.41795,286.8052L234.41795,334.1802 M224.73045,318.6177L224.73045,316.21145C224.73045,314.133325,224.121075,312.39895,222.91795,311.02395C221.6992,309.64895,220.1367,308.96145,218.1992,308.96145C216.0117,308.96145,214.29295,309.820825,213.0742,311.539575C211.839825,313.258325,211.23045,315.6177,211.23045,318.6177C211.23045,321.4302,211.8242,323.602075,213.0117,325.1177C214.1992,326.64895,215.839825,327.39895,217.9492,327.39895C219.9492,327.39895,221.5742,326.602075,222.839825,324.9927C224.089825,323.39895,224.73045,321.27395,224.73045,318.6177L224.73045,318.6177" Fill="Black" Height="48.156" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="35.531" Width="33.219"/>
            <Path Data="F1M271.47145,320.9927L250.59645,320.9927C250.924575,325.64895,253.84645,327.96145,259.3777,327.96145C262.893325,327.96145,265.987075,327.133325,268.65895,325.46145L268.65895,332.58645C265.6902,334.1802,261.84645,334.96145,257.1277,334.96145C251.955825,334.96145,247.9402,333.539575,245.09645,330.664575C242.237075,327.8052,240.8152,323.8052,240.8152,318.6802C240.8152,313.3677,242.34645,309.164575,245.4402,306.0552C248.518325,302.96145,252.3152,301.39895,256.8152,301.39895C261.47145,301.39895,265.080825,302.789575,267.643325,305.5552C270.1902,308.33645,271.47145,312.08645,271.47145,316.83645L271.47145,320.9927 M262.3152,314.9302C262.3152,310.352075,260.455825,308.0552,256.7527,308.0552C255.15895,308.0552,253.799575,308.71145,252.643325,310.02395C251.487075,311.33645,250.78395,312.977075,250.53395,314.9302L262.3152,314.9302" Fill="Black" Height="33.562" Canvas.Left="39.616" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="50.125" Width="30.656"/>
            <Path Data="F1M307.7517,334.1802L297.90795,334.1802L297.90795,329.3052L297.7517,329.3052C295.3142,333.08645,292.048575,334.96145,287.97045,334.96145C280.548575,334.96145,276.84545,330.477075,276.84545,321.4927L276.84545,302.1802L286.6892,302.1802L286.6892,320.6177C286.6892,325.14895,288.47045,327.39895,292.0642,327.39895C293.829825,327.39895,295.2517,326.789575,296.3142,325.539575C297.3767,324.3052,297.90795,322.6177,297.90795,320.4927L297.90795,302.1802L307.7517,302.1802L307.7517,334.1802" Fill="Black" Height="32.781" Canvas.Left="75.646" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="50.906" Width="30.906"/>
            <Path Data="F1M313.9717,333.33645L313.9717,325.33645C315.5967,326.320825,317.206075,327.0552,318.831075,327.52395C320.44045,328.008325,321.9717,328.2427,323.4092,328.2427C325.1592,328.2427,326.5342,328.008325,327.549825,327.52395C328.549825,327.0552,329.06545,326.320825,329.06545,325.33645C329.06545,324.71145,328.831075,324.195825,328.37795,323.77395C327.9092,323.3677,327.331075,322.9927,326.612325,322.6802C325.893575,322.3677,325.0967,322.08645,324.25295,321.83645C323.393575,321.58645,322.56545,321.3052,321.7842,320.9927C320.50295,320.52395,319.393575,320.008325,318.424825,319.445825C317.456075,318.89895,316.643575,318.258325,315.987325,317.52395C315.331075,316.8052,314.831075,315.96145,314.487325,314.9927C314.143575,314.039575,313.9717,312.89895,313.9717,311.58645C313.9717,309.8052,314.362325,308.258325,315.143575,306.96145C315.924825,305.6802,316.956075,304.6177,318.268575,303.789575C319.56545,302.977075,321.049825,302.3677,322.737325,301.977075C324.4092,301.602075,326.1592,301.39895,327.9717,301.39895C329.37795,301.39895,330.81545,301.508325,332.2842,301.727075C333.737325,301.945825,335.174825,302.27395,336.5967,302.6802L336.5967,310.3052C335.3467,309.58645,334.00295,309.039575,332.581075,308.664575C331.143575,308.3052,329.75295,308.1177,328.37795,308.1177C327.7217,308.1177,327.112325,308.1802,326.549825,308.289575C325.9717,308.414575,325.4717,308.570825,325.0342,308.789575C324.5967,309.008325,324.25295,309.289575,324.00295,309.633325C323.75295,309.977075,323.62795,310.3677,323.62795,310.8052C323.62795,311.39895,323.81545,311.89895,324.19045,312.3052C324.56545,312.727075,325.049825,313.08645,325.6592,313.383325C326.25295,313.695825,326.924825,313.96145,327.674825,314.195825C328.4092,314.445825,329.143575,314.6802,329.87795,314.9302C331.19045,315.39895,332.37795,315.89895,333.44045,316.4302C334.50295,316.977075,335.4092,317.6177,336.174825,318.33645C336.924825,319.070825,337.518575,319.9302,337.924825,320.89895C338.331075,321.883325,338.5342,323.0552,338.5342,324.39895C338.5342,326.3052,338.112325,327.914575,337.299825,329.258325C336.4717,330.602075,335.37795,331.695825,334.018575,332.539575C332.643575,333.383325,331.081075,334.008325,329.299825,334.383325C327.518575,334.758325,325.6592,334.96145,323.75295,334.96145C320.2217,334.96145,316.9717,334.414575,313.9717,333.33645L313.9717,333.33645" Fill="Black" Height="33.562" Canvas.Left="112.773" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="50.125" Width="24.562"/>
            <Path Data="F1M348.6317,334.96145C347.0067,334.96145,345.647325,334.46145,344.5692,333.46145C343.47545,332.46145,342.9442,331.2427,342.9442,329.77395C342.9442,328.27395,343.491075,327.0552,344.616075,326.08645C345.72545,325.133325,347.116075,324.64895,348.78795,324.64895C350.47545,324.64895,351.85045,325.133325,352.928575,326.102075C353.991075,327.070825,354.53795,328.3052,354.53795,329.77395C354.53795,331.3052,353.991075,332.539575,352.897325,333.508325C351.803575,334.477075,350.3817,334.96145,348.6317,334.96145L348.6317,334.96145" Fill="Black" Height="10.312" Canvas.Left="141.745" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="73.375" Width="11.594"/>
            <Path Data="F1M367.589875,334.1802L367.589875,255.758325L389.027375,255.758325C392.277375,255.758325,395.19925,256.195825,397.808625,257.070825C400.402375,257.945825,402.63675,259.1802,404.4805,260.758325C406.32425,262.352075,407.7305,264.258325,408.714875,266.477075C409.69925,268.695825,410.19925,271.14895,410.19925,273.8052C410.19925,276.070825,409.88675,278.1802,409.26175,280.14895C408.63675,282.1177,407.746125,283.914575,406.589875,285.539575C405.418,287.164575,403.9805,288.5552,402.293,289.7427C400.589875,290.9302,398.668,291.8677,396.527375,292.5552L396.527375,292.77395C399.152375,293.039575,401.527375,293.6802,403.683625,294.695825C405.839875,295.727075,407.683625,297.0552,409.214875,298.695825C410.746125,300.33645,411.918,302.258325,412.76175,304.46145C413.6055,306.664575,414.027375,309.070825,414.027375,311.695825C414.027375,315.02395,413.418,318.0552,412.214875,320.8052C411.01175,323.5552,409.32425,325.9302,407.152375,327.914575C404.9805,329.914575,402.402375,331.445825,399.418,332.539575C396.418,333.633325,393.121125,334.1802,389.527375,334.1802L367.589875,334.1802 M374.871125,262.4302L374.871125,290.258325L385.043,290.258325C387.69925,290.258325,390.089875,289.914575,392.246125,289.227075C394.402375,288.539575,396.246125,287.52395,397.777375,286.21145C399.308625,284.89895,400.4805,283.320825,401.308625,281.46145C402.121125,279.602075,402.543,277.508325,402.543,275.164575C402.543,266.6802,397.246125,262.4302,386.683625,262.4302L374.871125,262.4302 M374.871125,296.820825L374.871125,327.5552L388.371125,327.5552C394.168,327.5552,398.621125,326.21145,401.746125,323.4927C404.8555,320.77395,406.418,316.914575,406.418,311.914575C406.418,301.852075,399.57425,296.820825,385.918,296.820825L374.871125,296.820825" Fill="Black" Height="78.422" Canvas.Left="166.391" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="4.484" Width="46.438"/>
            <Path Data="F1M451.9635,335.4927C447.80725,335.4927,444.072875,334.789575,440.776,333.414575C437.479125,332.039575,434.666625,330.070825,432.3385,327.539575C429.99475,325.008325,428.2135,321.96145,426.979125,318.4302C425.729125,314.89895,425.11975,310.977075,425.11975,306.664575C425.11975,302.008325,425.776,297.83645,427.0885,294.14895C428.401,290.46145,430.260375,287.33645,432.68225,284.77395C435.104125,282.21145,438.026,280.2427,441.4635,278.89895C444.885375,277.5552,448.7135,276.8677,452.947875,276.8677C456.99475,276.8677,460.635375,277.539575,463.885375,278.8677C467.135375,280.195825,469.885375,282.1177,472.151,284.633325C474.401,287.14895,476.135375,290.21145,477.3385,293.820825C478.541625,297.4302,479.151,301.52395,479.151,306.1177C479.151,310.4927,478.510375,314.477075,477.260375,318.070825C475.99475,321.664575,474.197875,324.758325,471.86975,327.352075C469.526,329.945825,466.68225,331.945825,463.3385,333.3677C459.979125,334.77395,456.18225,335.4927,451.9635,335.4927L451.9635,335.4927 M452.510375,282.9302C449.447875,282.9302,446.666625,283.46145,444.197875,284.52395C441.7135,285.58645,439.5885,287.1177,437.822875,289.14895C436.05725,291.1802,434.697875,293.64895,433.760375,296.58645C432.80725,299.52395,432.3385,302.83645,432.3385,306.5552C432.3385,310.0552,432.80725,313.21145,433.760375,316.02395C434.697875,318.83645,436.041625,321.2427,437.776,323.2427C439.49475,325.2427,441.604125,326.789575,444.0885,327.8677C446.55725,328.945825,449.3385,329.477075,452.401,329.477075C455.526,329.477075,458.30725,328.96145,460.7135,327.914575C463.11975,326.883325,465.151,325.3677,466.8385,323.383325C468.510375,321.39895,469.776,318.96145,470.635375,316.08645C471.49475,313.21145,471.93225,309.914575,471.93225,306.227075C471.93225,298.695825,470.24475,292.9302,466.901,288.9302C463.541625,284.9302,458.74475,282.9302,452.510375,282.9302L452.510375,282.9302" Fill="Black" Height="58.625" Canvas.Left="223.921" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="25.594" Width="54.031"/>
            <Path Data="F1M516.1395,335.4927C511.98325,335.4927,508.248875,334.789575,504.952,333.414575C501.655125,332.039575,498.842625,330.070825,496.5145,327.539575C494.17075,325.008325,492.3895,321.96145,491.155125,318.4302C489.905125,314.89895,489.29575,310.977075,489.29575,306.664575C489.29575,302.008325,489.952,297.83645,491.2645,294.14895C492.577,290.46145,494.436375,287.33645,496.85825,284.77395C499.280125,282.21145,502.202,280.2427,505.6395,278.89895C509.061375,277.5552,512.8895,276.8677,517.123875,276.8677C521.17075,276.8677,524.811375,277.539575,528.061375,278.8677C531.311375,280.195825,534.061375,282.1177,536.327,284.633325C538.577,287.14895,540.311375,290.21145,541.5145,293.820825C542.717625,297.4302,543.327,301.52395,543.327,306.1177C543.327,310.4927,542.686375,314.477075,541.436375,318.070825C540.17075,321.664575,538.373875,324.758325,536.04575,327.352075C533.702,329.945825,530.85825,331.945825,527.5145,333.3677C524.155125,334.77395,520.35825,335.4927,516.1395,335.4927L516.1395,335.4927 M516.686375,282.9302C513.623875,282.9302,510.842625,283.46145,508.373875,284.52395C505.8895,285.58645,503.7645,287.1177,501.998875,289.14895C500.23325,291.1802,498.873875,293.64895,497.936375,296.58645C496.98325,299.52395,496.5145,302.83645,496.5145,306.5552C496.5145,310.0552,496.98325,313.21145,497.936375,316.02395C498.873875,318.83645,500.217625,321.2427,501.952,323.2427C503.67075,325.2427,505.780125,326.789575,508.2645,327.8677C510.73325,328.945825,513.5145,329.477075,516.577,329.477075C519.702,329.477075,522.48325,328.96145,524.8895,327.914575C527.29575,326.883325,529.327,325.3677,531.0145,323.383325C532.686375,321.39895,533.952,318.96145,534.811375,316.08645C535.67075,313.21145,536.10825,309.914575,536.10825,306.227075C536.10825,298.695825,534.42075,292.9302,531.077,288.9302C527.717625,284.9302,522.92075,282.9302,516.686375,282.9302L516.686375,282.9302" Fill="Black" Height="58.625" Canvas.Left="288.097" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="25.594" Width="54.031"/>
            <Path Data="F1M590.378,334.1802L564.628,306.883325L564.40925,306.883325L564.40925,334.1802L557.40925,334.1802L557.40925,251.27395L564.40925,251.27395L564.40925,304.258325L564.628,304.258325L589.0655,278.1802L598.206125,278.1802L571.956125,305.2427L600.28425,334.1802L590.378,334.1802" Fill="Black" Height="82.906" Canvas.Left="356.21" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="42.875"/>
 </Canvas>
 <Path Data="M233.418,287.8052L223.543,287.8052L223.543,306.8362L223.418,306.8362C221.793,303.8782,218.918,302.3992,214.793,302.3992C210.439,302.3992,206.918,303.9932,204.23,307.1802C201.543,310.3682,200.199,314.6072,200.199,319.8992C200.199,324.9612,201.418,328.9042,203.855,331.7272C206.293,334.5502,209.512,335.9612,213.512,335.9612C217.866,335.9612,221.168,334.2322,223.418,330.7742L223.543,330.7742L223.543,335.1802L233.418,335.1802L233.418,287.8052z M221.84,325.9932C220.579,327.5972,218.949,328.3992,216.949,328.3992C214.845,328.3992,213.199,327.6382,212.012,326.1182C210.824,324.5972,210.23,322.4302,210.23,319.6182C210.23,316.6182,210.845,314.2582,212.074,312.5392C213.303,310.8212,215.012,309.9612,217.199,309.9612C219.137,309.9612,220.71,310.6492,221.918,312.0242C223.126,313.3992,223.73,315.1282,223.73,317.2112L223.73,319.6182C223.73,322.2632,223.1,324.3882,221.84,325.9932z" Height="49.156" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="34.219" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-0.5,36.031,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M270.4805,317.8364C270.4805,313.0864,269.2045,309.3264,266.6525,306.5554C264.1005,303.7844,260.4905,302.3984,255.8245,302.3984C251.3245,302.3984,247.5325,303.9514,244.4495,307.0554C241.3655,310.1594,239.8245,314.3674,239.8245,319.6804C239.8245,324.8054,241.2515,328.8004,244.1055,331.6644C246.9595,334.5294,250.9695,335.9614,256.1365,335.9614C260.8655,335.9614,264.7095,335.1694,267.6675,333.5864L267.6675,326.4614C265.0015,328.1284,261.9075,328.9614,258.3865,328.9614C252.8655,328.9614,249.9385,326.6384,249.6055,321.9924L270.4805,321.9924L270.4805,317.8364z M249.5425,315.9304C249.7925,313.9724,250.4965,312.3364,251.6525,311.0234C252.8085,309.7114,254.1785,309.0554,255.7615,309.0554C259.4695,309.0554,261.3245,311.3474,261.3245,315.9304L249.5425,315.9304z" Height="34.563" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="31.656" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39.125,50.624,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M306.7617,303.1802L296.9177,303.1802L296.9177,321.4932C296.9177,323.6182,296.3867,325.3002,295.3237,326.5392C294.2617,327.7792,292.8447,328.3992,291.0737,328.3992C287.4907,328.3992,285.6987,326.1382,285.6987,321.6182L285.6987,303.1802L275.8557,303.1802L275.8557,322.4932C275.8557,331.4722,279.5637,335.9612,286.9807,335.9612C291.0637,335.9612,294.3237,334.0762,296.7617,330.3052L296.9177,330.3052L296.9177,335.1802L306.7617,335.1802L306.7617,303.1802z" Height="33.781" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="31.906" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75.157,51.406,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M322.7617,335.9614C324.6787,335.9614,326.5277,335.7684,328.3087,335.3834C330.0897,334.9984,331.6627,334.3834,333.0277,333.5394C334.3917,332.6954,335.4857,331.6024,336.3087,330.2584C337.1317,328.9144,337.5427,327.2944,337.5427,325.3984C337.5427,324.0444,337.3397,322.8784,336.9337,321.8984C336.5277,320.9194,335.9437,320.0654,335.1837,319.3364C334.4227,318.6074,333.5117,317.9724,332.4497,317.4304C331.3867,316.8884,330.1997,316.3884,328.8867,315.9304C328.1577,315.6804,327.4227,315.4354,326.6837,315.1954C325.9437,314.9564,325.2717,314.6854,324.6677,314.3834C324.0637,314.0814,323.5747,313.7224,323.1997,313.3054C322.8247,312.8884,322.6367,312.3884,322.6367,311.8054C322.6367,311.3674,322.7617,310.9774,323.0117,310.6334C323.2617,310.2894,323.6057,310.0084,324.0427,309.7894C324.4807,309.5704,324.9857,309.4044,325.5587,309.2894C326.1317,309.1754,326.7407,309.1174,327.3867,309.1174C328.7617,309.1174,330.1627,309.3004,331.5897,309.6644C333.0167,310.0294,334.3557,310.5764,335.6057,311.3054L335.6057,303.6804C334.1887,303.2634,332.7507,302.9454,331.2927,302.7274C329.8347,302.5084,328.3967,302.3984,326.9807,302.3984C325.1677,302.3984,323.4227,302.5914,321.7457,302.9774C320.0687,303.3624,318.5787,303.9664,317.2777,304.7894C315.9747,305.6124,314.9337,306.6694,314.1527,307.9614C313.3707,309.2534,312.9807,310.7944,312.9807,312.5864C312.9807,313.8984,313.1527,315.0344,313.4957,315.9924C313.8397,316.9514,314.3397,317.7944,314.9957,318.5234C315.6527,319.2534,316.4647,319.8944,317.4337,320.4454C318.4027,320.9984,319.5217,321.5134,320.7927,321.9924C321.5847,322.3054,322.4077,322.5864,323.2617,322.8364C324.1157,323.0864,324.9027,323.3674,325.6207,323.6804C326.3397,323.9924,326.9287,324.3574,327.3867,324.7734C327.8447,325.1904,328.0747,325.7114,328.0747,326.3364C328.0747,327.3154,327.5687,328.0444,326.5587,328.5234C325.5477,329.0034,324.1677,329.2424,322.4177,329.2424C320.9807,329.2424,319.4537,329.0034,317.8397,328.5234C316.2247,328.0444,314.6057,327.3154,312.9807,326.3364L312.9807,334.3364C315.9807,335.4194,319.2407,335.9614,322.7617,335.9614z" Height="34.563" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="25.562" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112.282,50.624,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M351.9023,334.5083C352.9963,333.5393,353.5433,332.2953,353.5433,330.7743C353.5433,329.2953,353.0063,328.0703,351.9333,327.1023C350.8603,326.1333,349.4803,325.6493,347.7933,325.6493C346.1263,325.6493,344.7353,326.1283,343.6213,327.0863C342.5063,328.0453,341.9493,329.2743,341.9493,330.7743C341.9493,332.2323,342.4903,333.4613,343.5743,334.4613C344.6573,335.4613,346.0113,335.9613,347.6363,335.9613C349.3863,335.9613,350.8083,335.4773,351.9023,334.5083z" Height="11.312" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="12.594" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141.25,73.875,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M388.5195,335.1802C392.1285,335.1802,395.4275,334.6332,398.4175,333.5392C401.4075,332.4462,403.9865,330.9062,406.1565,328.9182C408.3255,326.9312,410.0115,324.5622,411.2145,321.8092C412.4175,319.0562,413.0195,316.0212,413.0195,312.7032C413.0195,310.0782,412.5995,307.6642,411.7615,305.4572C410.9225,303.2522,409.7385,301.3282,408.2075,299.6882C406.6755,298.0472,404.8335,296.7172,402.6835,295.6962C400.5325,294.6762,398.1445,294.0372,395.5195,293.7822L395.5195,293.5632C397.6695,292.8712,399.5935,291.9312,401.2895,290.7462C402.9845,289.5622,404.4155,288.1582,405.5825,286.5352C406.7485,284.9142,407.6415,283.1172,408.2615,281.1492C408.8805,279.1802,409.1915,277.0662,409.1915,274.8052C409.1915,272.1442,408.6995,269.7012,407.7145,267.4772C406.7305,265.2542,405.3175,263.3482,403.4765,261.7622C401.6345,260.1762,399.4115,258.9462,396.8045,258.0712C394.1975,257.1962,391.2715,256.7582,388.0275,256.7582L366.5895,256.7582L366.5895,335.1802L388.5195,335.1802z M385.6755,263.4302C396.2485,263.4302,401.5355,267.6782,401.5355,276.1722C401.5355,278.5062,401.1245,280.6022,400.3045,282.4612C399.4845,284.3212,398.3085,285.9072,396.7775,287.2192C395.2465,288.5322,393.4045,289.5352,391.2535,290.2272C389.1025,290.9202,386.6965,291.2662,384.0355,291.2662L373.8635,291.2662L373.8635,263.4302L385.6755,263.4302z M384.9105,297.8282C398.5825,297.8282,405.4175,302.8602,405.4175,312.9222C405.4175,317.9182,403.8595,321.7732,400.7425,324.4892C397.6245,327.2052,393.1675,328.5632,387.3715,328.5632L373.8635,328.5632L373.8635,297.8282L384.9105,297.8282z" Height="79.422" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="47.43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165.891,4.984,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M462.293,334.3599C465.647,332.9379,468.49,330.9339,470.824,328.3439C473.157,325.7559,474.953,322.6659,476.211,319.0749C477.469,315.4849,478.098,311.5009,478.098,307.1259C478.098,302.5319,477.496,298.4299,476.293,294.8209C475.09,291.2119,473.357,288.1489,471.098,285.6329C468.837,283.1179,466.084,281.1949,462.84,279.8639C459.595,278.5329,455.949,277.8679,451.902,277.8679C447.673,277.8679,443.845,278.5429,440.418,279.8909C436.99,281.2399,434.064,283.1999,431.641,285.7699C429.216,288.3399,427.348,291.4669,426.035,295.1489C424.723,298.8319,424.066,303.0059,424.066,307.6719C424.066,311.9749,424.686,315.8949,425.926,319.4299C427.165,322.9669,428.951,326.0019,431.285,328.5359C433.618,331.0699,436.435,333.0289,439.734,334.4149C443.033,335.7999,446.762,336.4929,450.918,336.4929C455.147,336.4929,458.939,335.7819,462.293,334.3599z M465.848,289.9259C469.201,293.9189,470.879,299.6879,470.879,307.2349C470.879,310.9179,470.45,314.1989,469.594,317.0789C468.736,319.9589,467.47,322.3929,465.793,324.3799C464.115,326.3669,462.074,327.8799,459.668,328.9189C457.262,329.9579,454.49,330.4769,451.355,330.4769C448.293,330.4769,445.522,329.9399,443.043,328.8639C440.564,327.7889,438.458,326.2479,436.727,324.2429C434.994,322.2379,433.654,319.8319,432.707,317.0239C431.759,314.2169,431.285,311.0629,431.285,307.5629C431.285,303.8439,431.759,300.5179,432.707,297.5829C433.654,294.6489,435.013,292.1689,436.781,290.1449C438.549,288.1219,440.673,286.5819,443.152,285.5239C445.631,284.4669,448.402,283.9379,451.465,283.9379C457.699,283.9379,462.493,285.9339,465.848,289.9259z" Height="59.625" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Margin="223.367,26.094,201.601,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M526.4961,334.3599C529.8501,332.9379,532.6931,330.9339,535.0271,328.3439C537.3601,325.7559,539.1561,322.6659,540.4141,319.0749C541.6721,315.4849,542.3011,311.5009,542.3011,307.1259C542.3011,302.5319,541.6991,298.4299,540.4961,294.8209C539.2931,291.2119,537.5601,288.1489,535.3011,285.6329C533.0401,283.1179,530.2871,281.1949,527.0431,279.8639C523.7981,278.5329,520.1521,277.8679,516.1051,277.8679C511.8761,277.8679,508.0481,278.5429,504.6211,279.8909C501.1931,281.2399,498.2671,283.1999,495.8441,285.7699C493.4191,288.3399,491.5511,291.4669,490.2381,295.1489C488.9261,298.8319,488.2691,303.0059,488.2691,307.6719C488.2691,311.9749,488.8891,315.8949,490.1291,319.4299C491.3681,322.9669,493.1541,326.0019,495.4881,328.5359C497.8211,331.0699,500.6381,333.0289,503.9371,334.4149C507.2361,335.7999,510.9651,336.4929,515.1211,336.4929C519.3501,336.4929,523.1421,335.7819,526.4961,334.3599z M530.0511,289.9259C533.4041,293.9189,535.0821,299.6879,535.0821,307.2349C535.0821,310.9179,534.6531,314.1989,533.7971,317.0789C532.9391,319.9589,531.6731,322.3929,529.9961,324.3799C528.3181,326.3669,526.2771,327.8799,523.8711,328.9189C521.4651,329.9579,518.6931,330.4769,515.5581,330.4769C512.4961,330.4769,509.7251,329.9399,507.2461,328.8639C504.7671,327.7889,502.6611,326.2479,500.9301,324.2429C499.1971,322.2379,497.8571,319.8319,496.9101,317.0239C495.9621,314.2169,495.4881,311.0629,495.4881,307.5629C495.4881,303.8439,495.9621,300.5179,496.9101,297.5829C497.8571,294.6489,499.2161,292.1689,500.9841,290.1449C502.7521,288.1219,504.8761,286.5819,507.3551,285.5239C509.8341,284.4669,512.6051,283.9379,515.6681,283.9379C521.9021,283.9379,526.6961,285.9339,530.0511,289.9259z" Height="59.625" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="55.032" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,26.094,137.398,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <Path Data="M599.2852,335.1802L570.9572,306.2502L597.2072,279.1802L588.0742,279.1802L563.6292,305.2662L563.4102,305.2662L563.4102,252.2742L556.4102,252.2742L556.4102,335.1802L563.4102,335.1802L563.4102,307.8912L563.6292,307.8912L589.3872,335.1802L599.2852,335.1802z" Height="83.906" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Width="43.875" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0.5,80.414,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Now I understand that path's are basically lines from point to point.

Is there a way to scale an entire group of such path's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than explicitly scaling, I prefer to implicitly scale the paths.  First you need to combine the multiple paths into a single path using Blend.  Remove the Width and Height from the resulting path.  Then set the Stretch property to an appropriate value (often Fill or Uniform).  Then just put that shiny new path into something like a Grid and give the Grid some definite dimensions.  This gives you a reusable path that can be scaled up or down by its layout container.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In order to scale such a construct, one needs to group these elements (into a grid, for example) and apply Scale Transform to a Grid like this:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```